# Como hacer un input que se llene automaticamente con el contenido copiado en portapapeles en react

Tags: reactjs

Buen día tengo un input en react asi:

```
onInputChange (e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }

<div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4 '>
   <input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} name="cliente" type="text" className='validate'></input>
   <label  >Cliente</label>
</div>
```

Tambien un componente (nieto) que tiene un boton que copia un id de la siguiente manera:

```
onChange  ({target: {inputValue}}) {
    this.setState({inputValue, copied: false});
  };

onClick ({target: {innerHTML}}) {
   console.log(`Clicked on "${innerHTML}"!`);
   Materialize.toast('Id Copied!', 2000);
};

onCopy (text) {
    this.setState({copied: true});
    this.setState({ inputValue: text });
  };

<CopyToClipboard
  onCopy={this.onCopy}
  text={item.iddef_cliente}>
  <a className="btn-flat shadow btn-small waves-effect waves-light" onClick={this.onClick} onChange={this.idcopy}><i className="material-icons">content_copy</i></a>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

lo que quiero hacer es que el id que se copia en el componente se pegue automaticamente en el input.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es muy complicado lo que quieres hacer, para eso puedes definir un valor para tu campo en tu estado, y luego asignarlo al input que deseas. De la siguiente forma:

```
// donde defines tu state, normalmente en el constructor
this.state = {
   ...
   inputValue: '',
   ...
}
```

Ahora en tu input, debes hacer un bind de ese valor:

```
<input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} name="cliente" type="text" className='validate' />
```

Importante, modificar el método `onInputChange` para que pueda servir correctamente:

```
onInputChange(event) {
    ...  // estos tres puntos representan la lógica que ya tienes en este método
    this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value });  // guardamos en el state el valor del evento (lo que el usuario escribe);
}
```

Y ahora modificamos el método `onCopy` para que modifique ese estado también:

```
onCopy(text) {
  ...  // estos tres puntos representan la lógica que ya tienes en este método
  this.setState({ inputValue: text });  // esta linea hace la magia
}
```

Con eso debe ser suficiente, cualquier duda, o error, puedes comentarme y con gusto te ayudaré

Comment: Hola lamento molestar de nuevo pero sale un error `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined`

Comment: Seguramente no te has fijado bien en el código, pero si ves en `onCopy` recibe como parámetro una variable llamada `text` por eso sale así: `onCopy(text)` si no tienes nada adentro para recibir es decir, tu línea es igual a esto `onCopy()` entonces agregale el `text` y si ya tienes alguna otra entonces cambia `text` por la primera opción que tengas como parámetro de `onCopy`

Comment: Es correcto no habia modificado esa parte, aun asi no funciona, no se pega en el input el valor copiado no me marca ningun error pero no realiza la funcion.

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con lo que llevas de código hasta ahora? incluyendo los métodos: `onCopy` y `onInputChange`

Comment: Ya agregue la actualizacion del codigo veo que en consola en el input no me da valor alguno en consola

Comment: Viendo el código, tienes el mismo error que con el `onCopy` pero en `onInputChange` el evento que recibes lo nombraste como `e` pero sin embargo por copiar y pegar lo pusiste como `event`. Corrígelo y entonces deja esta linea así: `this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })`

Comment: si, me dicuenta jeje una disculpa. Aun asi no funciona

Comment: Cuando dices no funciona, obtienes algún error? la consola de desarrollador de javascript arroja algún mensaje?

Comment: No obteengo error alguno se que si copia el contenido por que se manda un mensaje en consola que dice que se copio el texto pero en el input no se refleja lo copiado y no me manda error y no aparece el value del input.

Comment: Si imprimes haces un `console.log(text)` dentro de la función `onCopy` que sale en pantalla? ¿Puedes crear un entorno donde pueda probar lo que estás haciendo? Un sandbox

Comment: con el console log me arroja el id que se copio. El problema debe estar en como paso los states desde el nieto al padre. no creo poder hacer el sandbox con los componentes que uso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92223/discussion-between-german-alzate-and-luis-enrique-gomez-perez).